# Cauchy's Residue Theorem contradiction?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the contour integral:
$$I=\oint_\Gamma \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}$$
Where $\Gamma$ is a circle at infinity and we have taken the branch cut to be between $z=\pm 1$. Now this function does not have any singularities (other then the branch points) so from Cauchy's residue theorem we would expect:
$$I=0$$
However, 
$$I=2\pi i$$
What is the reason for this contradiction, i.e. why doesn't Cauchy's residue theorem hold in this case?

**Edit - derivation of latter result**

$$I=\oint \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^{-2}}}dz$$
$$=\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(Re^{i \theta})^{-2}}} i d \theta$$
as $R\rightarrow \infty$ this becomes:
$$I=\int^{2 \pi}_0 i d\theta=2 \pi i$$

Comment: @Dr.MV I meant to say circular so, it is closed (sorry).

Comment: how do you define your function for $Im(z) > 0$ ? if you say $\sqrt{r e^{i \theta} } = \sqrt{r} e^{i \theta / 2}$ for $r > 0$ and $\theta \in [0;2\pi[$ that should work $f(z)$ will be holomorphic in the half plane $arg(z) \in ]0;\pi[$ and $\oint_\Gamma f(z) dz = 0$ with $\Gamma$ being a closed contour contained in  $arg(z) \in ]0;\pi[$

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi}$ is not a semicircle closed contour at all,  and ....

Comment: @user1952009 I know, its meant to be circular contour, I originally put semi-circular by mistake and then changed it soon after due to Dr. MV's comment

Comment: did you notice that the function has two branches : $f(z) = -f(z e^{2 i \pi})$ ? so on your closed circular contour, the function isn't even continuous

Comment: @user1952009 no it doesn't $f(z)=f(ze^{2 \pi i})$, this is one of the cases where going around both branch points takes you back to your initial value.

Comment: You do realize there's a singularity at infinity?  (... that your circle encloses once in the negative direction.)  Also, the integral $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}$ is elementary with antiderivative $\ln | x + \sqrt{x^2 - a^2}| + C$, so you can't avoid logarithmic involvement.  What do you get when you enclose one logarithmic singularity?  What do you get when you enclose two of them, but each containing a $\sqrt{x}$.  (I.e., colorfully: when you enclose two halves of a logarithmic singularity.)

Comment: The branch cut between $-1$ and $1$ has a residue of $1$. Any set where a function is not holomorphic can have a residue.

Comment: In short, $$I = -2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2-1}},\infty\biggr),$$ since the singularity at $\infty$ lies to the right of $\Gamma$.

Comment: @robjohn While I guess you can say that, talking about "residues of sets" is not standard terminology.

Answer (score 1):

In most complex analysis textbooks, residues are associated with *functions*, but in order to make sense of the residue at $\infty$, it's better to think of residues associated to $1$-forms. In your case (or in Yiorgos' example), the **function** is indeed holomorphic at $\infty$, but the **form**
$$
\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \qquad\big(\text{and } \frac{dz}{z} \big)
$$
has a non-zero residue at $\infty$. Intuitively, you can think of this coming from the singularity of $z$ as in $dz$ at $\infty$ (the function $z$ has a pole at $\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason 
$$
\oint\frac{dz}{z}=2\pi i.
$$ 
The function $f(z)=z^{-1}$ is analytic in $\mathbb C_\infty\setminus\{0\}$.

Cauchy's Residue Theorem holds in simply connected regions in $\mathbb C$. Not in $\mathbb C_\infty$.

Comment: The residue theorem holds for regions in the sphere, and being simply connected doesn't play a role (beyond making it unnecessary to state that the contour is nullhomologous).

Comment: So, what's wrong what my example?

Comment: I think you mean [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem) rather than the [Cauchy's Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

For $|z|\gt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{z^2-1}}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}z^{-2k-1}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\frac1z}+\frac1{2z^3}+\frac3{8z^5}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$
So the residue of the branch cut from $-1$ to $1$ is $1$.